# Задача по JQuery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование

Привяжите всем инпутам событие - по потери фокуса каждый инпут выводит свое value в абзац с id="test".

Comment: В чем сложности с выполнением задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Выбрать все элементы инпут, можно с помощью [селектора по тегу](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Добавить обработчик события потери фокуса в `jQuery` можно с помощью метода [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Внутри обработчика `this` будет указывать на сам `input`, и его значение можно получить с помощью свойства [`.value`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Для вывода значения в абзац с нужным `id`, сначала нужно выбрать этот абзац, воспользовавшись [селектором по `id`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Затем установить ему текст, с помощью метода [`.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)